# Distance between nodes LightGraphs julia

Tags: graph, julia, distance

I am wondering about how to compute the distance between a given pair of nodes, say nodes "i" and "j"
This is a minimal example for say nodes 2 and 12 from a Random Regular Graph with 100 nodes and connectivity 3

```
julia> using LightGraphs
julia> L = random_regular_graph(100, 3) 
julia> paths= dijkstra_shortest_paths(L, 2)
julia> distances = paths.dists
julia> d = distances[12]
```

The problem with this approach is that I have to calculate the distances between all the nodes and my node 2 in order to know the distance between my two nodes of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the shortest path from a specific source to a specific destination, consider using [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm):

```
julia> g = CycleGraph(10)
{10, 10} undirected simple Int64 graph

julia> a_star(g, 1, 8)
3-element Array{LightGraphs.SimpleGraphs.SimpleEdge{Int64},1}:
 Edge 1 => 10
 Edge 10 => 9
 Edge 9 => 8
```

If you are JUST interested in the (unweighted, unit) distances, use `gdistances`:

```
julia> gdistances(g, 1)[8]
3
```

In any case, do not access the `.dists` field from the `DijkstraResult`. Use the `dists()` method as the accessor. The internals of LightGraphs structs are not intended to be used directly.

Comment: Thank you @sbromberger! I think that the solution I was looking for it is: 
`length(a_star(g, 1, 8))`. However it seems that `gdistances(g, 1)[8]` is more efficient

Comment: It is MUCH more efficient to use `gdistances` over `a_star` OR `dijkstra_shortest_paths`. The reason is that by using unit weights, we can simply use the optimized frontier-based BFS to calculate the distances. This saves cycles and allocations, and is one of the fastest implementations of BFS around. (See, e.g., [Benchmark of popular graph/network packages v2](https://www.timlrx.com/2020/05/10/benchmark-of-popular-graph-network-packages-v2/).